# Netplan bond fails using WIFI and Ethernet on rpi4

Tags: networking, raspberrypi, netplan, debian

I don't know if this might be a bug, so I'll start asking in here :)

I'm running Debian on a RPI4 with Netplan controlling my network and both WIFI and Ethernet are working fine. But I'm running into some difficulties trying to setup a bond interface between my ETH0 and WLAN0. No matter what I try, bonding WIFI and Ethernet I'm getting the samme error generating the backend files.

config.yaml

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  bonds:
    bond0:
      interfaces:
        - eth0
        - wlan0
      addresses: [192.168.1.20/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.1.3, 192.168.1.1]
      parameters:
        mode: active-backup
        primary: eth0
        fail-over-mac-policy: active
  wifis:
    wlan0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      access-points:
        "MY SSID":
            password: "MY WPA KEY"
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
```

netplan --debug generate

```
DEBUG:command generate: running ['/lib/netplan/generate']
** (generate:15114): DEBUG: 18:46:27.488: Processing input file /etc/netplan/config.yaml..
** (generate:15114): DEBUG: 18:46:27.489: starting new processing pass
** (generate:15114): DEBUG: 18:46:27.489: recording missing yaml_node_t eth0
** (generate:15114): DEBUG: 18:46:27.489: recording missing yaml_node_t wlan0
** (generate:15114): DEBUG: 18:46:27.489: recording missing yaml_node_t eth0
** (generate:15114): DEBUG: 18:46:27.489: wlan0: adding wifi AP 'MY SSID'
** (generate:15114): DEBUG: 18:46:27.489: starting new processing pass
** (generate:15114): DEBUG: 18:46:27.489: wlan0: adding wifi AP 'MY SSID'
/etc/netplan/config.yaml:22:9: Error in network definition: wlan0: Duplicate access point SSID 'MY SSID'
        "MY SSID":
        ^
```

I'm not an expert and I think I have done almost anything :) If I remove the bond interface and only be using WLAN and/or ETH with DHCP/Static ip everything are generating right and working as intended. I'm properly be doing something wrong, but I don't know what :(

Any suggestions? :)

Best Regards
Soren

Comment: We only support official Ubuntu versions here. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the netplan parser.  To file a bug against netplan upstream, please use https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan.

Comment: Thanks for reply. https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/1903287